# No file or Directory error when using pandas.read_excel in Databricks

Tags: pandas, databricks

I am baffled by the behaviour of Databricks:

Below you can see the contents of the directory using `dbutils` in Databricks. It shows the `test.xlsx` file clearly in directory (and I can even open it using `dbutils.fs.head`) But when I go to use `panda.read_excel` to read it, I get the error below stating it can't be found...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an exact cause for this error but the workaround was the following:

1.) Made sure I was on DB run time v13.0 exactly.
2.) And I ran this code inside the `Repos` folder inside Databricks (Earlier I was in the `Workspace` folder)

The code seemed to run fine after that.